# Htaccess cache issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is driving me completely crazy.

I've been using URL rewriting on this freshly installed server for custom URLs, but it seems that whatever URL rewriting rule I write in htaccess will be taken into account forever..

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/calendar/$       /calendar.php [QSA,L]
```

Even if I remove the line, Apache will still take it into account.

Even if I DELETE .htaccess, the ghost content will still be applied... I assume there is some kind of cache somewhere; how do I turn it off..??..

Thanks!

Comment: usually, restarting apache is enough to clear any cached configuration.. Are you sure that the .htaccess is the *only* place where you defined that rule? Plus, doublecheck any other caching configuration / proxy / etc. that might be between you and the apache server

Comment: I restarted Apache, I even restarted the whole machine.Yes I'm using only 1 .htaccess. There is no other caching configuration possible as one of the rules had (.*) and I can generate new URLs that will still get me to the old pages. So that's definitely a server-side issue :(

Comment: Did you also flush your browser cache? Although it should not be the case, since the default redirection happens with a non-permanent code, so the browser should repeat the request.

Comment: Yeah .. it could be browser .. or proxy cache. Please check the response headers (look for ones with "cache"). If you have Firebug for Firefox -- then on "Net" panel you can tell it to display cached responses as well (or use httpFox extension).

Comment: It's not the browser. I used differents browsers and even differents computers from differents ISPs. It's definitely an Apache issue. Responses were 200. I "solved" the problem by creating a new VHost with new directory and it isn't acting up like the old one, but this problem is still a mystery. Apparently a few other people had the same problem as me.

Comment: I get the same issue, when you delete the .htacces it still applys the rewrite rules :S - If i reboot my machine it resets, there must be some option hidden away that caches the htacces file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it was a long time ago, I believe rebooting the whole server fixes it. Otherwise, creating a new VHost and a new directory for the files will do the trick..

Answer (score -1):

did you try restarting apache? try throwing in a 
    sudo service apache2 restart