# Issue delete htaccess redirecting www to non www

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, web

some days ago i upload this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

now I want delete this redirect. I already delete .htaccess file but rediret still working.

I don't want redirect non www to www.

plz help me.

Comment: Sounds like you've got multiple `.htacess` files, e.g. in a subdirectory which you are using or in  a parent directory.

Comment: I had the same issue. I changed my browser just to test. And it worked on other browser. So try clearing browser history and cache. If it still don't work try restarting your servers.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878995/htaccess-cache-issues

Answer (score 1):

Since you deleted the .htaccess file.. it should work..

Just try deleting your browser cache.

If you're using chrome:

```
I am on Mac and this is the shortcut: Shift+Command+Delete.

On Windows, it is: Ctrl+Shift+Delete.
```

Comment: This is most certainly a caching issue. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached by the browser (and possibly intermediary caches). +1